# How to create a nested spatie/data-transfer-object array with different types

Tags: php, laravel, dto

I'm using [v2 of spatie/data-transfer-object](https://github.com/spatie/data-transfer-object/tree/v2) and can't figure out the following:

This is the input

```php
$object = [
    'parameters' => [
        [
            'name' => 'foo',
            'type' => 'text',
            'value' => 'bar'
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'baz',
            'type' => 'select',
            'values' => ['foo', 'bar']
        ]
    ]
];
```

and these are the type definitions:

```php
namespace Formio\Dto;

use Spatie\DataTransferObject\FlexibleDataTransferObject;

class Content extends FlexibleDataTransferObject
{
    /** @var \Formio\Dto\Parameters[] $parameters */
    public array $parameters;
}

// file Parameters.php
class Parameters extends FlexibleDataTransferObject
{
    public string $name;
    public string $type;
}
```

```php
$dto = \Formio\Dto\Content($object)
```

In the current setup, the `parameters.*.value` and `parameters.*.values` are missing in the  `$dto` object.

My question is, how can I apply a different type definition on `parameters` depending on `parameters.*.type`?

So that I can apply

```php
class ParametersSelect extends FlexibleDataTransferObject
{
    public string $name;
    public string $type;
    public array $values;
}
```

in the `Content` class? Do I use a method that loops through `parameters` and applies the correct `Parameters*` type class?

PS: this is not a laravel question per se (hence the tag) but an iteration of this package for laravel exists so maybe someone from the community came across this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it the following way:

Create a method that checks for the `type` and instantiate the correct `Parameters*` class.

```php
// file Parameters.php
namespace Formio\Dto;

use Spatie\DataTransferObject\FlexibleDataTransferObject;

abstract class Parameters extends FlexibleDataTransferObject
{
    public string $name;
    public string $type;

    public static function createFromArray(array $parameters)
    {
        switch($parameters['type']) {
            case 'select':
                return new ParametersSelect($parameters);
            default:
                return new ParametersText($parameters);
        }
    }
}

class ParametersSelect extends Parameters
{
    public array $values;
}

class ParametersText extends Parameters
{
    public string $value;
}
```

The function `array_map` will iterate over every `parameters`, and for each one it will call `Parameters::createFromArray($param)`, which will return an instance of `Parameters` based on the `type` it finds in the `$param` array.

```php
namespace Formio\Dto;

use Spatie\DataTransferObject\FlexibleDataTransferObject;

class Content extends FlexibleDataTransferObject
{
    public Parameters $parameters;

    public function __construct(array $parameters)
    {
        parent::__construct($parameters);

        $this->parameters = array_map(function($param) {
            return \Formio\Dto\Parameters::createFromArray($param);
        }, $this->parameters);
    }
}
```